# Is there a cataloging software that links with Goodreads?

Tags: software-recommendation, sync, books

I have been experimenting with Tellico collection management software. I like how easy it is to use and that it will create all kinds of collections for any kind of medium (movies, books, games). The thing I would really like to be able to do is sync this with my Goodreads account so when I enter a book into the collection on Goodreads or on Tellico they will sync. Any ideas if this is possible or if there is another software like Tellico that has this capability? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> calibre is a free and open source e-book library management
>   application developed by users of e-books for users of e-books. It has
>   a cornucopia of features divided into the following main categories:
>
> - Library Management
>
> calibre manages your e-book collection for you. It is designed around
>   the concept of the logical book, i.e., a single
>   entry in your library that may correspond to actual e-book files in
>   several formats.
>
> calibre can sort the books in your library by: Title, Author, Date
>   added, Date published, Size, Rating, Series, etc.<sup>1</sup>

You can install it fro the Ubuntu Software center.

[image]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source: [goodreads.com](http://www.goodreads.com/ereaders/106-calibre)</sup>

Comment: I love calibre but I wanted something that would allow me to have my shelves from Goodreads to sync. Thanks though.